# How do I make my category sort orders keep from reverting to different order in admin view?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, admin-panel, category-tree, sort

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1. When I am in Catalog/Manage Categories I am finding that the sort order that I am dragging my categories into is not staying the same. I have caching disabled as this is a development store.

Question: How do I make my category admin sort order stay the same without it reverting to a previous order?

And on another probably related issue, I notice that sometimes when I click on a category in the left sidebar that has nested subcategories, the plus sign will go away and the only way for me to see the subcategories is to refresh the page.

I there a way perhaps to import my categories back into Magento with the sort orders in the correct positions?

Any suggestions on these problems? Thanks All!

Comment: Anyone have even a suggestion? I am getting tired of dragging my backend categories to the order I want them in and then seeing them different again after I refresh my browser. Makes the view order on the frontend wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old question. Worth an answer though.

Looks like /js/ext-tree/ext-tree.js was an old version and not updated.

Why this happens? Your positions are all being set to 1, except for the category that your drag, which gets changed to 2. Another category drag sets all categories to position 1, resetting any changes you had made.

Magento then uses category entity_id in order to get the sort order. This then means that you end up with a very odd navigation and that new categories always end up last